# distribution function of $X_t = B_t^2 - t$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, martingales

I have tested that the process $X_t = B_t^2 - t$, where $B_t$ is an standard brownian motion $\mathcal{N}(0,t)$, is a martingal and now need to find is distribuition. I know that $B_t^2$ has a $\mathcal{X}$-squred distribution with 1 degree of freedom, but how can I use this fact to get to the distribution of $X_t$

Comment: Don't forget the scaling. I think it is $B_t^2-t = tU-t=t(U-1)$ where $U$ is $\chi$-squared with one degree of freedom.

Comment: @angryavian why would $tU = B_t^2$?

Comment: The distribution of $B_t$ is $N(0, t)$, not $N(0, 1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to have this question answered not in the comments.

The Brownian motion respects $B(0)=0$ and $B(t'+t)-B(t') \sim N(\mu=0,\sigma^2=t)$.

This means:

1. $B(t) \sim N(0,t)$. Therefore $B(t) \sim \sqrt{t}Z$, where $Z$ is a standard Gaussian variable.
2. This implies: $B^2(t) \sim tZ^2 \sim t\chi_1^2$, and $B^2(t)-t \sim t\chi_1^2-t$
3. $P(B^2(t)-t\le x)=P(t\chi_1^2-t \le x)=P(\chi_1^2\le \frac{x+t}{t})$

Taking derivatives of the above c.d.f. we get the p.d.f. of our  variable:

$f_{B^2-t}(x)=\frac{1}{t}f_{\chi_1^2}(\frac{x+t}{t})$